# Trying to use regex after already using regex once

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code and I've got the id and name value in its own square bracket as shown below. How can I access the value of id and name?

```js
let data = "[[id=3, name=BOX-3, description=test, comment=test, locationId=5, capacity=null]];"

        let id = data.match(/(?<=id=)\d+(?=\,)/g);
        let name = data.match(/(?<=name=)[\w|-]*/g);

console.log(data);
console.log(id);
console.log(name);


console.log(id.match(/(?<=\[)[^\][]*(?=])/g) );

//console.log(idVal);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the result to get the match.

```js
let data = "[[id=3, name=BOX-3, description=test, comment=test, locationId=5, capacity=null]];"
let [id] = data.match(/(?<=id=)\d+(?=\,)/g);
let [name] = data.match(/(?<=name=)[\w|-]*/g);

console.log(id);
console.log(name);
```